# Weird, consistent ~10s network redirecting delays with Safari, Chromium, various services

Tags: networking, safari, google-search

I've got a bit of a mystery - I primarily search using the Safari address bar (with Google), and pretty often it's unresponsive for 10s. When using the web inspector, it shows that there's a long wait for "Redirects." However, there's nothing in the headers where it shows 200 vs a 300 exception.

I believe that I'm seeing this in other network requests, but this one is the one that happens the most on a daily basis. So far I've changed the DNS to 1.1.1.1 with no change in the behavior.

Any ideas to what might be going on? Is this just a Safari bug to be reported to Apple?

[image: Web inspector screenshot]

Edit: same thing happened, but with many requests, with Slack:
[image]. All those requests also have the same behavior with "Redirects" and very strange that they're all around the same amount of time.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question. Rather, it is about using your web browsers to search Google.

Comment: I understand how it can seem that way, @StephenOstermiller. However, this is something that I'm seeing across the board with connections across applications (including the application that we're developing, where APIs for multiple services are behaving this way). So, it's a programming/debugging question. I updated the title to be more general.

Comment: @togume Did you ever get this resolved? I am having a very similar issue (redirects in Saari, but never 'too many' and stalling in Chrome) that happens only on a Cloudflare-proxied subdomain. Been trying for weeks to get to the bottom of it.